# Spring MVC and Twitter Bootstrap template

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

Good Evening,
I am creating a project based on Spring MVC for the back end and Twitter Bootstrap for the front end.
I would like to create a template for recurring my pages (header and footer fixed for all pages) only that I would like to avoid repeating the code in all the pages (as it is not good practice and can lead to mistakes). Is there a way to centralize what? I thought about the jsp (one for the header and the footer) and recall within the various view. Is there a way to do so? Or there better alternatives?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JSP... There's `include` tag, you can use like this:

```
<%@ include file="/views/templates/header.jsp" %>
// Rest of the content
<%@ include file="/views/templates/footer.jsp" %>
```

Or you can use a framework for templates, like Tiles or Freemarker.

Spring MVC with Tiles: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-tiles-3-integration

Using tiles, the template page:

```
<body>
<div class="container" style="border: #C1C1C1 solid 1px; border-radius:10px;">
    <!-- Header -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    <!-- Body Page -->
    <div class="span-19 last">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <!-- Footer Page -->
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</div>
</body>
```

And you can change dynamically the "body" tiles attribute.